# React Native: How I can select Title and Description texts in screen (/page)

Tags: react-native

I want to **Select Texts**. I have some **'title'** and **'description'** in different `<Text>` elements. If I put them together in parent `<Text selectable={true}>` element, I can't give some styles to my title and description
`<Text>title</Text>`
`<Text>description</Text>` , e.g. (for title-`textAlign: 'center'`, for description - `textAlign: 'left'`).
What can I do? Maybe you know some ('text-selectable-container') component for this situation, or any another variant?

Comment: You want to copy the title and descriptions together? put them in one `Text` component and set the parent `Text` component `selectable={true}`, you can put `Text` inside `Text`.
But I don't know if it would be a good UX practice.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that React Native apps are not web apps, they natively convert the RN controls to native controls. You are trying to use a `<Text>` control which renders natively as `UILabel` on iOS and `Label` on Android. These do not support selecting a text.

If you want to allow your users to select text without a WebView, you can use a [`TextInput`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput), which I don't think you are trying to implement either.

So the only way to implement what you want is to use a web view! There's many libraries you can use for this, just remember to not use [the deprecated one](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.61/webview)

Answer (score 0):

What I understand that you want to give different stylings to title and description. You can do like this

```js
<View>
  <Text style={{textAlign:'center'}}>This is the title</Text>
  <Text style={{textAlign:'left'}}>Tis is my description</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: It's not work. I want to select Texts. View is not selectable for Texts

Comment: Can you please write your code and please explain what do you mean by select texts ?

Comment: I have this part of text, I want to select this two text items or part. in View it is not possible I mean.  

<Text style={title}>Custom UI, App Branding & Custom Animations</Text>

<Text style={desc}>
A common trend in mobile apps is to share the same app layout and design across iOS and Android. The brand identity is becoming more important than strictly sticking to platform aesthetics.
</Text>

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code

```
<Text selectable>
  <Text style={{textAlign:'center'}}>title</Text>
  <Text style={{textAlign:'left'}}>{`\ndescription`}</Text>
</Text>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In this way, I can't set some styles to child <Text>s

Comment: Can you tell me the style property or share an ss of design?